# Querying nested objects which has an array of objects in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, schema

I have a collection with the following schema:

```js
        {
            "id": "1",
            "properties": [
                { "key": "key1", "value": "8" },
                { "key": "key2", "value": "5" }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "properties": [
                { "key": "key1", "value": "2" },
                { "key": "key2", "value": "5" }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "3",
            "properties": [
                { "key": "key1", "value": "9" },
                { "key": "key2", "value": "9" }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "4",
            "properties": [
                { "key": "key1", "value": "6" },
                { "key": "key2", "value": "5" }
            ]
        }
        // so on...
```

Now I have an array of filters, for example, [{ "key": "key2", "value": "5" }, { "key": "key1", "value": "6" }]. I want my response to be the following because both objs with ids 1 and 2 have { "key": "key2", "value": "5" } in their properties field. And obj with id 4 because of { "key": "key1", "value": "6" }.

Because everything is so nested, what would be the best way to approach this?

```js
        {
            "id": "1",
            "properties": [
                { "key": "key1", "value": "8" },
                { "key": "key2", "value": "5" }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "properties": [
                { "key": "key1", "value": "2" },
                { "key": "key2", "value": "5" }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "4",
            "properties": [
                { "key": "key1", "value": "6" },
                { "key": "key2", "value": "5" }
            ]
        }
```

Comment: Did it work or still having any issues?

Comment: @srinivasy it works but in the real code I have an array of filters but not individual filters. Is there a way to map over the array and use the $or?

Comment: Updated my answer, please check it.

Comment: @srinivasy, $in works if only properties satisfies at least one filter (which is my original question). What happens if I need it to satisfy all filters, can I still use $and somehow or is there another way

Comment: Do you mean to say you need documents where all passed in objects(filters) should exist in properties array of every document in result ?

Comment: that's correct. All the keys and values should match

Comment: Ok, your question has completely changed !!! In these kind of situations please either close this question & raise a new one with all new requirements but Kindly do not club all with the original post - which makes this question not readable, anyhow updated my answer please check it.. :-)

Comment: Ah got it sorry! Will keep that in mind next time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you're looking for documents with at least one matching filter from `[{ "key": "key2", "value": "5" }, { "key": "key1", "value": "6" }]`, Just try this, a simple [$or](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/index.html) or [$in](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/index.html#use-the-in-operator-to-match-values-in-an-array) should work here, or just in case if you need both has to be matched use [$elemMatch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/index.html) :

```
db.getCollection('yourCollection').find({
    $or: [{
        properties: {
            "key": "key1",
            "value": "8"
        }
    }, {
        properties:
        {
            "key": "key2",
            "value": "5"
        }
    }]
})
```

**Updated w.r.t. new requirement as you can directly pass an array of objects with below (This works if you need to match at least one) [$in](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/index.html#use-the-in-operator-to-match-values-in-an-array) :**

```
let arrayFilters = [{
    "key": "key1",
    "value": "8"
}, {
    "key": "key2",
    "value": "5"
}]

db.getCollection('yourCollection').find({ properties: { $in: arrayFilters } })
```

**New requirement is to get documents where properties array should contain all passed filters(objects) instead of at least one, then use [$all](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/all/index.html) :**

```
let arrayFilters = [{
    "key": "key1",
    "value": "8"
}, {
    "key": "key2",
    "value": "5"
}]
db.getCollection('yourCollection').find({ properties: { $all: arrayFilters } })
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your filter requirements, you have to use the [`$elemMatch (query)`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/index.html#elemmatch-query) and execute the below query:

```
db.getCollection('collectionName').find({
    $or: 
    [
        {
            properties: 
                { 
                    $elemMatch: {
                        "key": "key1",
                        "value": "8"
                    }
            }
        },
        {
            properties: 
                { 
                    $elemMatch: {
                        "key": "key2",
                        "value": "5"
                    }
                }
        }
    ]
})
```

Output of the above query:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5de7233eccbdb9c5fc6183da"), "id" : "1", "properties" : [ { "key" : "key1", "value" : "8" }, { "key" : "key2", "value" : "5" } ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5de7233eccbdb9c5fc6183db"), "id" : "2", "properties" : [ { "key" : "key1", "value" : "2" }, { "key" : "key2", "value" : "5" } ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5de7233eccbdb9c5fc6183dd"), "id" : "4", "properties" : [ { "key" : "key1", "value" : "6" }, { "key" : "key2", "value" : "5" } ] }
```

Comment: As per the req, I don't think you need to use to $elemMatch, within $or, a simple $or should suffice. Explanation : `$elemMatch` is not needed when you're trying to fetch the exact match of object(being passed in filter) & in `$or`, If you've given your answer looking at `survey` example of https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/#examples , then you need to try execute below & check difference ::

Comment: `db.Survey.find( { results: { product: "xyz", score: 5 } } ) && db.Survey.find( { results: { product: "xyz", score: { $gte: 8 } } } ) && db.Survey.find( { 'results.product': "xyz", 'results.score': { $gte: 8 } } ) && finally $element only works here, all of above doesn't. db.Survey.find( { results: { $elemMatch: { product: "xyz", score: { $gte: 8 } } } } )` , So here we don't have a condition on any object in filter, we've plain objects in filter query, So we no need use `$elemMatch`, it would be an add-on unnecessary stage in this query :-)

Comment: @srinivasy Thanks for the brief explanation, upvoted your answer, it explains everything that the user has asked for.